# Breaking up a file into two parts based on a particular line

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, perl

I need to breakup a file into two separate files based on a particular line for example:

```
.
.
sc_outfifo 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 1.586E-02 1.586E-02 1.586E-02
Fub_Level_DACGE(%) PS0_SI.0 PS0_SI.0 PS0_SI.0 PS1_SI.0 PS1_SI.0 
siunit 98.91 98.81 98.91 90.06 96.37 81.37 81.37 16655
.
.
```

So all the lines above `Fub_Level_DACGE(%)` goes in one file and the rest including `Fub_Level_DACGE(%)` goes in another file. Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

The utility that's actually designed for this is `csplit`

```
NAME
       csplit - split a file into sections determined by context lines

SYNOPSIS
       csplit [OPTION]... FILE PATTERN...
```

So in this case

```
csplit file /Fub_Level_DACGE\(%\)/
```

will produce files `xx00` and `xx01` containing the two parts.

Comment: Unix has a tool for everything.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

This will read file `file0` and write its lines to `file1` until the line starting `Fub_Level_DACGE` is reached.  Starting with that line, all lines are written to `file2`:

```
awk -v f=file1 '/^Fub_Level_DACGE/{f="file2"} {print>f}' file0
```

#### How it works

- `-v f=file1`

  Set the variable `f` to the name of the initial output file, `file1`.
- `/^Fub_Level_DACGE/{f="file2"}`

  When we reach the line which starts `Fub_Level_DACGE`, assign to `f` the name of the second output file, `file2`.
- `print>f`

  Write the current line to the file whose name is in `f`.